# Inheriting class but setting to instance of base class error

Tags: java

I am trying to add some functionality to a class from a closed API(from a jar) in java.

```
public class NewPlayer extends OldPlayer {
    public int NewFunction(){
        return 0;
    }
}
//instance.GetPlayer() return an OldPlayer object, so I get an error, this function cannot be changed
NewPlayer p = instance.GetPlayer();
```

If I just cast `instance.GetPlayer()` to `NewPlayer`, this compiles.

```
NewPlayer p = (NewPlayer)instance.GetPlayer();
```

Is this the proper way to handle this?  Is there a better approach?   Is the proper way to extend functionality of a closed source class just extending it?

Tldr: I want to add functionality to a class from a closed source object from a jar library

Comment: Suppose you had `Duck extends Animal`.  Could you take something you only knew was an `Animal` and call it a `Duck`?  It only works the other way.

Comment: Casting doesn't change one type of object into another type, it's merely a compile-time way of treating an object *as if it were* a specific class. You'd have to hope that there's some way to register new classes so that the factory method GetPlayer can return something other than an OldPlayer.

Comment: You would get a ClassCastException at run-time. The instance would need to be overriden too or something else. However hacks would be imaginable.

Comment: Then how do I approach this?

Comment: @JoopEggen what would be the proper way to  approach what I am trying to do then? Not really looking for a hack solution

Comment: You could make OldPlayer a member of NewPlayer instead of inheriting.

Comment: @jacksons5j One cannot tell, from (1) what's said about the API and maybe (2) what you want to achieve. I do not see anyone answering the question. One would need to have/know the library, and know your requirements. There are tools like AOP to intercept methods and other rather esoteric means. For now it does not look feasible.